# Is there any benchmark tool for FUSE file systems?

Tags: linux, performance, testing, filesystems, fuse

I was searching for a benchmark tool for some FUSE file system implementation, I found a file system benchmark tool in general which is called [iozone](http://www.iozone.org/), but it seems that it has problems specifically with FUSE, it actually didn't work for me...

Comment: Which problems with FUSE? Can you give an example or a link? All file-based benchmarking tool should work. A FUSE filesystem should not be different than an in-kernel file system.

Comment: For file system benchmarking tools in general, there are a lots of stackoverflow "threads". The usual suspects are filebench, fio, sysbench, .......

Answer (score 1):

If `iozone` gives poor results with a FUSE filesystem, I'd say that just means the filesystem or FUSE has problems in general, which will cause you to see poor performance in actual use of the filesystem. That's certainly been my experience: I have yet to see a FUSE based filesystem that performs anywhere near what you get with an in-kernel filesystem.

Personally, I find [Bonnie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/) easier to use and its results easier to interpret. But, I don't expect it to give qualitatively different results than you'd get from IOzone.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little script called [fs-performance](https://github.com/marook/fs-performance) to evaluate the performance of my own fuse file system. The script itself is very alpha. It only supports measurement of ls operations right now.